# Generic Function as return

Tags: typescript, types

This function is valid:

```
function useStateCorrect<T>(initState: T): [() => T, (state: T) => void] {
  let _state = initState;
  return [
    (): T => { return _state },
    (state: T) => {
      _state = state;
    }
  ];
}
```

**What do I have to do so that this one is also valid?**
(Here I simply tried to extract the returns as types)

```
type stateGetter = <T>() => T;
type stateSetter = <T>(state: T) => void;

function useStateError<T>(initState: T): [stateGetter, stateSetter] {
  let _state = initState;
  return [
    (): T => { return _state },
    (state: T) => {
      _state = state;
    }
  ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `stateSetter`/`stateGetter` [generic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-types) (the `<T>` is on the left-hand side of the `=`), and to pass `T` on to them when defining the function's return type. Right now, you have types that define [generic functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions) instead, which are similar but different.

So:

```typescript
type StateGetter<T> = () => T;
//              ^^^
type StateSetter<T> = (state: T) => void;
//              ^^^

function useStateError<T>(
    initState: T
): [StateGetter<T>, StateSetter<T>] {
//             ^^^             ^^^
    let _state = initState;
    return [
        (): T => {
            return _state;
        },
        (state: T) => {
            _state = state;
        },
    ];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIHELCQJwDwBUB8UAvFABQCURBOA3AFAD09UzLrrAep7aJLAkjDSZcBYiQDO-CAC4oOCoQIA3APYBLACZ1GbXS07tatAGYBXAHYBjYGpXmop8RDiIIAUQwYV2fCVqs1czVgFyRZHFoyWQBtUJQhCB88ABo+V0F0RJEAXSgAbwYmPTYDYpKuVgAbNCgAfUlXIihA4Li6Vgw0Uwx7aP89cnDKfP6yqE7gbvt6qXa9AF9k0bYJKXCFAgKx5hnG4gakOd1F5ey6edogA)

*(Note: I capitalized `StateGetter` and `StateSetter` because non-primitive types [other than `object`] are generally capitalized.)*